# How to split vector into subsets?

Tags: c++, process, mpi

I'm trying to split the vector into subsets based of the number of process I use in my application. I created the pseudo code but I really don't have any clue how can I output the subsets.

The problem:

> Read a subset of the address records from residences.dat using
>   striping. For n processes, each process evaluates a unique subset of
>   records based on every nth record. The number of records in this
>   subset should be approximately #-of-residence-records /#-of-processes. Across all the parallel processes used no address should be omitted and none should be processed more than once. Also
>   note that only ONE record at a time should be stored in memory by any
>   process

My code:

```
std::vector<Residence> spliteResidenceDaata(vector<Residence> rs,int numProces = 0);
function body 

    std::vector<Residence> spliteResidenceDaata(vector<Residence> rs,int numProces)
    {

        std::vector<Residence> residenceSet;
        //get the size of vector
        int res_set_size = rs.size();
        int sizrOfSubSet =res_set_size/numProces;

        //output the arry subsite some "help here"

        return residenceSet;
    }
```

update

```
I came up with this pseudo code
1-take the number of line in .dat file  rData
2- get the number of data you want to read for each process sizeofLine  (rData.size()/numProc)
3- read the .dat file from line 0 to  sizeofLine
4-output array
```

Comment: any ideas or suggestion are welcome ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to read one record at time not pass the all subset as vector think you need this 
    while(!residenceFile.eof())
    {
        residenceFile >> res.x >>res.y;

```
    if ( numLines % numProcs == rank)
    {
        //call the  process
        //populate_distancesVector(res,foodbankData);
        analysis_range(populate_distancesVector(res,foodbankData),count);

    }
    ++numLines;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

i haven't tested this code, but something along the lines of this should work - instead of having your function return one vector, have it return a vector of vectors, like this:

`std::vector<std::vector<Residence>> split(std::vector<Residence rs, int num_procs)`

this will allow you to split your original vector into `num_procs` number of vectors, and then `push_back()` each of those onto your return vector of vectors (kind of like a matrix).

```
std::vector<std::vector<Residence>> split(const std::vector<Residence> rs, const unsigned num_procs) {
    unsigned j = 0; //position counter
    std::vector<std::vector<Residence>> result; //resulting vector of vectors
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < num_procs; ++i) {   //for each process
        std::vector<Residence> temp;            //create a vector
        for(; j < ((i + 1) * rs.size() / num_procs; ++j)    //iterate
            temp.push_back(rs[j]);              //and populate temporary vector with a 1/num_procs section of original vector
        result.push_back(temp);                 //and push that temporary vector into your result vector of vectors
    }
    for(; j < rs.size(); ++j)                   //finally, if the original vector is not divisible by num_procs
        result[num_procs].push_back(rs[j]);     //push the remainder of elements into the last vector
}
```

when you call the function, it will look something like this:

`std::vector<std::vector<Residence>> vectors = split(original_vector, 4);`

which will allow you to get subvectors like this:

```
vectors[0];   //first quarter
vectors[1];   //second
vectors[2];   //third
vectors[3];   //fourth + remainder
```